# What's the best file system for a 200TB Array on a MacOS 10.7?

Tags: storage, mac-osx-server, zfs

We have a Mac server (10.7) with a 200TB disk array. We're trying to decide between HFS+ and the unsupported ZFS. Which should we use, why, and is there another choice that we haven't considered?

Comment: "(Un)Supported" would seem to be the key word here. If you end up with data loss/corruption from using an unsupported filesystem, Apple will likely tell you to get lost and use the FS that ships with the OS.

Comment: I agree with @JamesO'Gorman. I love ZFS but it's not a good idea to do anything that the vendor considers unsupported (unless you're comfortable with the potential consequences).

Comment: We are a CS department and have been using ZFS on another server for more than a year without incident.  I wonder who it was who felt the need to down vote my question. Apple doesn't even support 200TB on a server.

Comment: How good is your backup system?  How much down-time can you afford if that system dies, and you need to do a restore?

Comment: @vy32 The first two comments explain the down vote.

Comment: @sysadmin1138: As vy32 states: HFS+ isn't supported either. So I find this question relevant too. What to do if you are caught between a rock and a hard place ?

Comment: @tonny Do what our compsci department did. Use FreeBSD and zfs.

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to ask here. You know ZFS on OSX server is unsupported. You presumably know what "unsupported" actually means. Only you know how risk-averse you are and how dependant on vendor support you wish to be.

Comment: If you want 200TB of well documented and supported storage, don't buy it direct attached to a mac. That said, I think HFS+ supports as large a volume you want to create.

Comment: Being a research institution, we don't care if it is "supported" or not. We care what will give us the best performance and not lose data.

Comment: My apologies. From your last comment, I was clearly wrong when I assumed you understood what "unsupported" meant in this context.

Comment: Unsupported means that you can't complain to Apple that it doesn't work. We can't complain to Apple for the majority of the work that we do. ZFS has a user community and we have used it for years on other systems without data loss. But I do not know about the relative performance of ZFS vs. HFS+. I also do not know if there are other options on Mac hardware. Yes, we can run FreeBSD on the hardware, but I am not sure about fibre channel drives and 10Gig drivers for FreeBSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2422?viewlocale=en_US) correctly, there is no practical limit the the size of filesystem you can create with HFS Plus. ZFS is unsupported, so unless you're using this for a throwaway scratchpad, your only choice is HFS plus.